# no implicit conversion of String into Integer, simple ruby function not working

Tags: ruby

When I run this code I get a typeError, but when I do it by hand in the IRB everything seems to be working out okay. I believe the problem lies somewhere in my IF statement but I don't know how to fix it.

```
numerals = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
def convertToNumbers(string)
  arr = string.downcase.split('')
  new_array = []
  arr.each do |i|
      if (arr[i] =~ [a-z])
          numValue = numerals.index(arr[i]).to_s
          new_array.push(numValue)
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: You should be a using a text editor with good code highlighting. It would have helped you notice your typo.

Comment: You appear to be doing arr.each |i|, but then doing arr[i] instead of just i.

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant

```
arr[i] =~ /[a-z]/
```

which matches the characters a through z. What you wrote

```
arr[i] =~ [a-z]
```

is constructing an array and trying to compare it using the regex comparison operator, which is a type error (assuming variables a and z are defined).

Comment: Thank you for the response but I'm still getting the same error when i run the program

Answer (score 2):

A few issues.  As Tyler pointed out inside of the loop you are still referencing arr when you look to only need to use i.  Also, the regex issue Max pointed out is valid as well.  The function also will return arr and not the new_array array as that is the result of the for loop output.

I made a few modifications.

```
def convertToNumbers(string)
  numerals = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
  arr = string.downcase.split('')
  new_array = []
  arr.each do |i|
      if (i =~ /[a-z]/)
          numValue = numerals.index(i).to_s
          new_array.push(numValue)
      end
  end
  new_array.join
end

puts convertToNumbers('abcd');
```

which prints out '0123'